# Delete elements from numpy array by value

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays that represent 2D coordinates. Each row represents `(x, y)` pairs:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5]])
b = np.array([[1, 1], [5, 5], [3, 2]])
```

I would like to remove elements from `a` which are in `b` efficiently. So the result would be:

```
array([[2, 1], [3, 1], [3, 3]])
```

I can do it by looping and comparing, I was hoping I could do it easier.

Comment: This is a duplicate, I apologize, I did make a search, but was not able to find the answer.

Comment: @enedene No worries, marking a question as a duplicate isn't an accusation or chastisement, it's really more of a pointer to a place where there are already answers.  You asked the question more clearly, imo, but the answers already exist there.

Answer (score 1):

Python `sets` does a nice job of giving differences.  It doesn't, though, maintain order

```
np.array(list(set(tuple(x) for x in a.tolist()).difference(set(tuple(x) for x in b.tolist()))))
```

Or to use boolean indexing, use broadcasting to create an `outer equals`, and `sum` with `any` and `all`

```
A = np.all((a[None,:,:]==b[:,None,:]),axis=-1)
A = np.any(A,axis=0)
a[~A,:]
```

Or make `a` and `b` complex:

```
ac = np.dot(a,[1,1j])
bc = np.dot(b,[1,1j])
A = np.any(ac==bc[:,None],axis=0)
a[~A,:]
```

or to use `setxor1d`

```
xx = np.setxor1d(ac,bc)
# array([ 2.+1.j,  3.+1.j,  3.+3.j])
np.array([xx.real,xx.imag],dtype=int).T
```

=================

```
In [222]: ac = np.dot(a,[1,1j])
     ...: bc = np.dot(b,[1,1j])
In [223]: ac
Out[223]: array([ 1.+1.j,  2.+1.j,  3.+1.j,  3.+2.j,  3.+3.j,  5.+5.j])
In [225]: bc
Out[225]: array([ 1.+1.j,  5.+5.j,  3.+2.j])
In [226]: ac == bc[:,None]
Out[226]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I'm curious to know how making a and b complex would solve this.  I see that it works, but it would be great to know why.

Comment: Making them complex combines each pair into one complex number.  And equality has been defined for complex numbers.  It's just another way of reducing the dimensionality of the problem.